# Only Edit some fields and "SaveChanges" fill the missing fields with default values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model class,

```
public class MyModel 
{ 
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public DateTime D { get; set; }
}
```

In the edit screen, I only need to edit `A and B. And the following will overwrite C and D with default values (0 and '0001-01-01'. How to keep the existed values (in the database table) for C and D besides include them in the view and hide them?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel myModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db_Entry(myModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your model really looks like, but in your controller, I typically do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel myModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var existEntry = _db.YourEntity.firstOrDefault(o => A == o.A);
        if(existEntry != null){
          existEntry.A = myModel.A;
          existEntry.B = myModel.B;
          _db.SaveChanges();
        }        
    }
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Of course, this depends really on your model specifics to get the existing entry, and perhaps you don't like this method in which case the other answer might be more suited to your needs.

EDIT: Basically, the way I usually handle this is to get the existing object from the db, update that, and then submit the changes, thus updating only the properties you care about and leaving the rest as they are.

Comment: I want to keep the original values of C, D in the database table.

Comment: Ahh I see. I misunderstood. Well then. Let me edit my answer with what I would do, and you can take it or leave it!

Comment: The `Edit` action should never add a record though.

Comment: So leave that part out. It was late when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Make a view model that has A and B properties.

```
public class ViewModel 
{
  public int A {get;set;}
  public int B {get;set;}
}
```

Then make this as your parameter in your controller then map it to your model class.

Comment: So I will still need to back-fill `C` and `D` from the existed record after mapping the view model to model class for `db.SaveChanges`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.updatemodel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (or [TryUpdateModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). It updates an existing entity, but only for properties it can find in the value provider; other properties remain intact.

Typically you use it like to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, TModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    // Invalid model; redisplay view
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();

    var entity = db.Entity.Find(id);

    // Entity not found; return 404
    if (entity == null) return HttpNotFound();

    // Everything OK; update entity and redirect back
    UpdateModel(entity);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: The parameter `model` has all the member of `TModel` since its type is `TModel`. For example, the `DateTime` property of the `TModel` which doesn't exist in the View will be filled with the value of `0001-01-01` (I tried to "quick watch" in Visual studio). Curiously, how does `UpdateModel()` know if a property exists in the viwe?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. TModel in this case is the view model type, so it only has those properties you want to make editable. It doesn't necessarily have to have all properties of your entity model. UpdateModel doesn't know which properties exist in the view, but it does know what properties it finds in the value provider.

Comment: In other words, using your own example, your EF entity has all properties, A, B, C, and D. TModel has only A and B.